# Bracketing and convergence issues in series representation of $\ln(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I was recently working on some problems involving the Taylor- Series expansion of $\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})$.

The problem asked to prove that for (natural) $n$:
$$\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) < \frac{1}{n}$$

The solution brackets all the expansion terms of degree 2 and 3 together, using the fact that the sequence $\frac{1}{kn^k}$ decreases monotonically in $k$, then the terms 4 and 5 and so forth.

As I saw the solution, I wondered if this operation was legitimate.
Given the fact that the power series does not converge absolutely, doesn't the Riemann rearrangement theorem apply?
Does one need an $\epsilon$, $\delta$ argument here or is this rigorous?

Comment: Taylor series for $\ln (1+x)$ converges absolutely for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Ok, that's trivial. Thank you.
For general reference, is bracketing a rearrangement operation?

Comment: Consider also that $\log(1+x)<x$ is equivalent to $e^x>x+1$, which is trivial by the convexity of the exponential function.

Comment: No, bracketing is not a rearrangement operation. Bracketing is always legitimate.